# Ordinal log-loss in a multiclass classification in XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, loss-function

I have a multi-class problem that which classes are simultaneously mutually exclusive and have ordering. You can think of the classes as being some score: 0 (Low), 1 (Medium), 2 (High).

What I would like to do is make a custom loss function that will capture this characteristic. Following from [Section 7.2.1](https://peopleanalytics-regression-book.org/ord-reg.html).

XGBoost's documentation gives the loss function $L(\theta)$ for a binary classification, which is simply the log-likelihood as given by:

$$
L(\theta) = \sum_{i}[y_{i}ln(1+e^{-\hat{y}}) + (1-y_{i})ln(1-e^{-\hat{y}})].\\
$$

Although not documented, I would assume that for multiclass with softmax:

$$
L(\theta) = \sum_{i}[y_{i,1}ln(\frac{e^{\hat{y_{i,1}}}}{\sum_j^{k}e^{\hat{y_{i,j}}}}) + y_{i,2}ln(\frac{e^{\hat{y_{i,2}}}}{\sum_j^{k}e^{\hat{y_{i,j}}}}) + ... y_{i,m}ln(\frac{e^{\hat{y_{i,m}}}}{\sum_j^{k}e^{\hat{y_{i,j}}}})]
$$

From here, two questions follow:

1. Since XGBoost does not provide a ordinal loss, I can only adjust the loss function *after* the softmax transformation. This is problematic because in the proportional log-odds (ordinal) problem  we have:

$$
P(y=1) = P(y^*<\tau_{1}) = P(\alpha + \beta X + \epsilon < \tau_{1}) = P(\epsilon < \tau_{1} - \alpha - \beta X ) = \frac{1}{1+e^{(\tau_{1} - \alpha - \beta X)}}
$$

which in XGBoost's case will be:

$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{(\tau_{1} - \hat{y})}}
$$

Since I cannot invert the softmax function without a constant to get \hat{y}, this is problematic ..
If you could do this then I would assume that you can then simply just sum the log-probabilities to get the log-likelihood as your desired loss.

2. In XGBoost, when you are coding the custom loss (see, [code snippet](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html)), `predt` and `dtrain` are provided to you; if you input a multiclass vector suitable for ordinal classification, `dtrain` will be, e.g., `[0,0,1,3,2]`, and `predt` will be a matrix of probabilities, which is the softmax-transformed $\hat{y_{i,j}}$ for each observation $i$ and class $j$. However, the ordinal problem, following from above, seems to be one-dimensional (it resembles more a binary classification than multinominal), so I am not fully understanding how can you work with this. I have checked out the following [post](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html) which explains some differences in encoding, but this affects the `dtrain` if anything and not the probabilities. I have also looked at the `statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model.OrderedModel` implementation and they do accept a vector of integers (e.g., `[0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2]`) as their `exog` variable, so I am assuming this is possible to implement.

I have cross-posted this also at [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631367/232706)